# No matching distribution found for pymqi==1.12.0 even if the version is on the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pymqi

I'm getting "No matching distribution found" error even though the version that I asked for is in the list suggested by pip. Has anyone faced this problem before ?

I am using Python 3.6.8 and pip 21.3.1.

```
$ python -m pip install pymqi==1.12.0
Collecting pymqi==1.12.0
  Using cached pymqi-1.12.0.tar.gz (75 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qqk862ea\\pymqi_435a0bb65f7143dc90a321b8cd537fe6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qqk862ea\\pymqi_435a0bb65f7143dc90a321b8cd537fe6\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-vnbxwi_4'
       cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qqk862ea\pymqi_435a0bb65f7143dc90a321b8cd537fe6\
  Complete output (9 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qqk862ea\pymqi_435a0bb65f7143dc90a321b8cd537fe6\setup.py", line 133, in <module>
      library_dirs, include_dirs, libraries = get_windows_settings()
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qqk862ea\pymqi_435a0bb65f7143dc90a321b8cd537fe6\setup.py", line 41, in get_windows_settings
      r'{}\tools\Lib64'.format(os.environ['MQ_FILE_PATH'])]
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
      raise KeyError(key) from None
  KeyError: 'MQ_FILE_PATH'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/33/c567a624e7c09a5ab50352dc2aa586fbdf75fbe185d55a2d1d027fe685b2/pymqi-1.12.0.tar.gz#sha256=ca18659242f34ff3484b454fd872036a87b285c214e0907353c815e12e46cb75 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pymqi/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymqi==1.12.0 (from versions: 1.0.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.2.post1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.9.0.post1, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.3, 1.12.5, 1.12.6, 1.12.7, 1.12.8)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pymqi==1.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at the error:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qqk862ea\pymqi_435a0bb65f7143dc90a321b8cd537fe6\setup.py", line 41, in get_windows_settings
      r'{}\tools\Lib64'.format(os.environ['MQ_FILE_PATH'])]
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
      raise KeyError(key) from None
  KeyError: 'MQ_FILE_PATH'
```

This error tells that the `MQ_FILE_PATH` environment variable is not set. Set this environment variable before running `python -m pip install pymqi==1.12.0`.

---

Note: The check of the presence of the `MQ_FILE_PATH` environment variable has been fixed in later versions of `pymqi`. See [this Pull Request](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/pull/223) in the pymqi GitHub repository.